# What are all the objects/characters in this Gremlins poster?

Tags: character-identification, object-identification

I have identified many of these (but it will take longer to post them in a follow-up answer), but I can't get all of them. I have numbered the objects I can discern as distinct, for ease of tracking. Some numbers were accidentally missed or duplicated, but my end result should be all unique identifiers.

[image]

[ORIGINAL HERE](http://www.syfy.com/sites/syfy/files/2017/10/gre.jpg)

[ORIGINAL STORY](http://www.syfy.com/syfywire/new-gremlins-poster-crawls-into-a-curiosity-shop-of-horror-movie-easter-eggs)

(I added what I knew to the original community wiki).

Comment: fwiw - the poster is from Hero Complex Gallery - https://hcgart.com/ - SyFy just shared that it existed and is available (I say this because the title made me think there is a SyFy Gremlins series on the way)

Comment: Legend available here (spoiler alert): https://i.kinja-img.com/gawker-media/image/upload/s--9-xwVsRz--/c_scale,fl_progressive,q_80,w_800/hxpgb3sqw1uhswoo4kym.jpg

Comment: Variant posted here w/ color differences enable better visibility for some objects: https://i.kinja-img.com/gawker-media/image/upload/s--oVnilhmn--/c_scale,fl_progressive,q_80,w_800/rqvhes9kzbttmyc59jlz.jpg

Comment: @NKCampbell Nice. I did a reverse image search and it didn't come up with much, so I (faultily) assumed it was a SyFy thing. Kudos on the legend.

Comment: HQ version of the key is [here](https://larryfire.files.wordpress.com/2017/10/22279914_701724640031140_463922773018231587_n.jpg)

Comment: Supposed key cannot be trusted when the very first identified item is wrong. Bubo is not in *Jason and the Argonauts*.

Comment: @phantom42 - I think the artist generally makes the key. It can be trusted because even referencing Jason and the Argonauts, while an incorrect movie title, does make the intent clear - also - you can see more clearly here that the eyes appear more Bubo-esque than Hedwig - https://i.kinja-img.com/gawker-media/image/upload/s--oVnilhmn--/c_scale,fl_progressive,q_80,w_800/rqvhes9kzbttmyc59jlz.jpg

Comment: Note that it's not possible that all of these items were actually in the shop in *Gremlins* since many of them came along after *Gremlins* was made.

Comment: I'm not saying that it's Hedwig. It's clearly Bubo, but Bubo was only in the Clash of the Titan movies. While creators often make keys like this, so do random internet users.

Answer (score 3):

Bold is unidentified.

A [(possibly unofficial) legend is apparently available](https://i.kinja-img.com/gawker-media/image/upload/s--9-xwVsRz--/c_scale,fl_progressive,q_80,w_800/hxpgb3sqw1uhswoo4kym.jpg) but the resolution is low and hard to read. Also, some of the listed objects, such as Bubo, appear in different/multiple works.

Quadrant I:

- 1. Bubo from *Clash of the Titans* 1981
- 2. Just Bubo's cage.
- 3. **Freddy Krueger's Glove**
- 4. Orca nameplate from *Jaws*
- 5. Rocketeer Jetpack from *The Rocketeer*
- 6. The Power Sword from *Masters of the Universe*
- 7. **A mounted "golden ticket" to Willie Wonka's Chocolate Factory**
- 8. Cobra Kai shirt from *The Karate Kid*
- 9. **Doctor Zaius from *Planet of the Apes***
- 10. Vigo the Carpathian from *Ghostbusters 2*
- 11. NY Yankees hat on Short-Round/Chinese Kid (see 12)
- 12. Short-Round from *Indiana Jones and the Temple of Doom* or "Chinese Kid" from *Gremlins*
- 13. Mr. Wing (proprietor of curios shop in *Gremlins*
- 14. Leg Lamp from *A Christmas Story*
- 15. Poster for Shaw vs. Balboa fight from *Rocky IV*
- 16. Randal Peltzer from *Gremlins*
- 17. **Possibly Monkey Brains from *Indian Jones and the Temple of Doom***
- 18. **Creature in a jar (Spider? Face-hugger?)**
- 19. Shield from House Stark from *Game of Thrones*
- 20. Captain America's Shield

Quadrant II:

- 21. Jason Vorheese's hockey mask
- 22. **Doc Brown's mind reading invention from *Back To The Future***
- 23. **A book?**
- 24. **A mask**
- 25. V's Guy Fawkes mask
- 26. **A sign**
- 27. **An arched object**
- 28. Stick figure from *Blair Witch Project
- 29. Camp Crystal Lake sign from *Friday the 13th*
- 30. Loki's mask from *The Mask*
- 31. Inigo Montoya's sword from *The Princess Bride*
- 32. **The book from *The Neverending Story***
- 33. **A blockish object**
- 34. **???**
- 34x. **Something in a jar**
- 35. **???**
- 36. **???**
- 37. **???**
- 38. Zoltar fortune teller machine from *BIG*
- 39. Talking door knocker from *Labyrinth*
- 40. **Light in the shape of a logographic**
- 41. Logo of the arcade game "The Last Starfighter" from the movie of the same name.
- 42. Label of the arcade game "The Last Starfighter" from the movie of the same name.
- 43. Glaive from *Krull*
- 44. Wilson from *Cast Away*
- 45. **A bottle**
- 46. Fire stone from *The Fifth Element*
- 47. **A book?**
- 48. **A laying down book? Label begins with "T"?**
- 49. One-Eye Willie's Skull Key from *The Goonies*
- 50. The Necronomicon from *The Evil Dead/Army of Darkness*
- 51. **???**
- 52. **??? Object with glowing portion**
- 53. The Holy Grail from *Indian Jones and the Last Crusade*
- 54. Puzzle box from *Hellraiser*
- 55. **A scaled egg**
- 56. **???**

Quadrant III:

- 57. [Tik-Tok of Oz](http://oz.wikia.com/wiki/File:Tik_tok_return_to_oz_by_randomobsessor-d68igp7.jpg)
- 58. Short-Round from *Indiana Jones and the Temple of Doom*
- 59. Carpet from *The Shining*
- 60. **Shriveled head or creature in a jar**
- 61. [Lion-O's sword](https://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/thundercats/images/7/7e/619px-Vlcsnap-2014-03-12-21h52m32s82.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20140322204508) from Thundercats
- 62. **Stack of books**
- 63. **A sword**
- 64. The Maltese Falcon
- 65. **A wooden handle on some sort of pick/rapier?**
- 66. John Hammond's cane from *Jurassic Park*
- 67. **???**
- 68. **???**
- 69. **Brain in a jar**
- 70. Little Guy from *Batteries Not Included*
- 72. **Acme Invisible Ink from *Who Framed Roger Rabbit?***
- 72x. Thermal Detonator from *Return of the Jedi*
- 73. Demogorgon from *Stranger Things*
- 74. **Some sort of pin, clasp or knife?**
- 75. Ruby slippers from *The Wizard of Oz*
- 76. **A briefcase with an odd pattern on front**
- 77. **Some type of large device**
- 78. **A barrel**

Quadrant IV:

- 79. Holy Hand Grenade from *Monty Python and the Holy Grail*
- 80. Chuckie Doll from *Child's Play*
- 81. **A lampost or odd chalice?**
- 82. **Something weird in a jar**
- 83. **A framed picture?**
- 85. **A chest with a radioactive symbol on it**
- 85x. The Trap from *Ghostbusters*
- 86. **A rug with triangular symbols**
- 87. **A squashed bug?**
- 88. Cobb's top from Inception
- 89. **A carved horse figurine**
- 90. **A small replice of The Statue of David by Michelangelo from *The Goonies***
- 91. The Heart of the Ocean from *Titanic*
- 92. Orion's Belt from *Men in Black*
- 93. **A large chest**
- 94. Gizmo from *Gremlins*
- 95. Jack Sparrow's Piece of Eight from *Pirates of the Caribbean*
- 96. **A crate with chicken wire**
- 97. **A figurine that looks like a knight**
- 98. **A figurine that looks like a deep sea diver?**
- 99. **Another figurine**
- 100. **A short knife or cane with a metal handle/knob**
- 101. Origami unicorn from *Blade Runner*

Comment: I think the kid is just the kid that sold the Mogwai to the inventor. https://youtu.be/IbpUA7bwTWk?t=29

Comment: No. 6 is He-Man's sword

Comment: 89 is from the Goonies, 90% certain, would need to see if the thingie is upside down to be 100%

Comment: 42 is the text on the arcade game ["The Last Starfighter"](https://www.arcade-museum.com/game_detail.php?game_id=8394), from the [movie with the same name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Last_Starfighter). Please excuse me while I fondly remember the 80ies for the next few hours or so ... :)

Comment: 41 is the logo of the arcade game "The Last Starfighter", so both 41 and 42 belong to [the arcade machine](https://www.arcade-museum.com/images/118/1181242126127.jpg).

Comment: I think #7 is a mounted [golden ticket to Willie Wonka's chocolate factory](https://goo.gl/images/vszwaV).

Comment: #22 looks like [Doc Brown's mind reading headgear](https://goo.gl/images/zbxss5) from *Back To The Future*.

Comment: If you're looking for [*The Neverending Story* book](https://goo.gl/images/BsnfjZ), (cause it's gotta be there, right?) it's obvious that's what is written on the cover of 32.

Comment: #36 is [the golden idol](https://goo.gl/images/lA5dzv) from the beginning of *Raiders of the Lost Ark*.

Comment: #47 is the [Handbook for the Recently Deceased](https://goo.gl/images/ZhScCP) from *Beetlejuice*. Yeah.. I watched every single movie in the 80's like 20 times each.

Comment: #86 has some of the same shapes in it as [the magic carpet](https://goo.gl/images/TdU5o9) from *Alladin*, but the sizes and layout seem wrong. Oh I think just remembered the horse!!!

Comment: Isn't #89 one of Kevin's toys from *Time Bandits*? I can't find a picture of it. Perhaps it was given to him by Agamemnon and he still has it after getting back home?

Comment: #69 Is the [abnormal brain](https://goo.gl/images/bHU2uh) from *Young Frankenstein*.

Comment: #74 of the [pin worn by the hand of the king/queen](https://goo.gl/images/TPFVsF) in *Game of Thrones*.

Comment: #48 is a [TGRI tube](https://goo.gl/images/QPbzDD) from *Teenage Mutant Ninja Turtles*.

Comment: #60 is a [guardian](https://goo.gl/images/XkyJw5) (what it sees, Lo-Pan knows) from *Big Trouble In Little China* (love this movie!).

Comment: Pretty sure #65 is the handle of the umbrella (from what I don't know) that is also #68. Could be Mary Poppins or Being There? Ah, yep. First search - it's her [umbrella](https://goo.gl/images/GtbjtT) from *Mary Poppins*.

Comment: #69 is "abnormal" brain in a jar from Mel Brook's "Young Frankenstein", referred to as "A.B.Normal"